# EF Code First - Property of type Type

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have an object that has a property of type Type:

```
public ScheduledJob
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Type JobType { get; set; }
    public string JobParameters { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the code-first migrations, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.SortedEntityTypeIndex.Add(EdmEntitySet entitySet, EdmEntityType entityType)
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingService.Analyze()
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
    at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
    at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

What is the best way to make this scenario work?

**Edit for @NSGaga's post:**

The whole model (simplified) is this:

All job objects implement the following interface:

```
public interface IJob
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
    void Run();
}
```

Each of the jobs has its own properties used as a sort of parameter:

```
public class ProcessMedia : IJob
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public int MediaContentID { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        if(MediaContentID <= 0)
             throw new Exception("Missing parameter MediaContentID");
        //work
    }
}
```

I use this model for an asynchronous job processing system, which works fine. Now, I'm trying to build a scheduler, where I can give it a job type and parameters (serialized to string) and have it run on intervals.

Comment: Save the fully qualified type name as a string.

Comment: I was doing this before, I was just checking to see if there was a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post I made few days ago...

[How should I define a field that can take various data types in EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927829/how-should-i-define-a-field-that-can-take-various-data-types-in-ef/15933621#15933621)

**Why are you doing this ?**

You almost never need to save the `Type` as such.

> @David mentioned already what to do.

But I'd further discourage you to go that way - but rather rethink.

The EF code first is about having 'strong-typed' entities. You can have nice 'inheritance' working, w/o a need to save a Type.

If you need something like an 'enum type' out of a limited # - use an enum or an int.

You can post your model and I'll point you out if it could be changed.

---

I think you could use inheritance for what you need.
Make different types of Jobs entities.

e.g. take a look at this solution here (my post earlier)
[Multiple Inheritance Levels in EF Code Firs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885279/multiple-inheritance-levels-in-ef-code-firs/15891061#15891061)
...and let me know if problems, questions when you try something.

Maybe it's easier to use TPH (like it's in there), they all get stored in the same table - and you get less problems usually.

Comment: I've updated the original post to show more of the model details and reasoning.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct textbook answer, but it is not the best answer for what I'm building. If I used inheritance, it would require the developers to build a data migration script each time they create a new job. I would really like to avoid that since we may end up with many many different job types. I went with @davin-tryon's suggestion, to store the assembly qualified name and get the type from that.

Comment: that's ok, every problem is specific - you could also add an 'enum' and each class can redefine it's own unique enum value (providing you / user has a control over it, and it's finite). That'd also take just one 'int' (or less) in the Db, instead of the whole, big string. But I also recommended David's answer as the most direct to your question.